# How can measure the minimum value in LTspice monte carlo simulation curve?

Tags: ltspice, monte-carlo

Attached the LTspice curve result of the monte carlo simulation.
[image]
How can measure the minimum value from the curve. Here it show only the middle values while measuring. What setting change should be done.

Comment: With a .meas min statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you press the up down keys you can select different curves.

A [.meas statement](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_MEASURE_Evaluate_User_Defined_Electrical_Quantities.htm) could also do this but I haven't tried it personally with a .step simulation.

You can [export files](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1815) if lt spice won't give you the information you want.